# EF 6 Find Generates Derived From Statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm confused on why EF 6's Find method generates a derived query. I ran the following two statements in LinqPad:

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var z = ctx.TicketTracker.Find(11277);
                var x = ctx.TicketTracker.Where(w => w.TicketTrackerId == 11277).FirstOrDefault();
                
            }
```

Here's the output:

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[TicketTrackerId] AS [TicketTrackerId], 
[Limit1].[BusinessId] AS [BusinessId], 
[Limit1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], 
[Limit1].[ETicketStorageId] AS [ETicketStorageId], 
[Limit1].[TicketJSON] AS [TicketJSON], 
[Limit1].[DriverUpdateId] AS [DriverUpdateId], 
[Limit1].[OrderNumber] AS [OrderNumber], 
[Limit1].[OrderKey] AS [OrderKey], 
[Limit1].[TicketNumber] AS [TicketNumber], 
[Limit1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
[Limit1].[VehicleId] AS [VehicleId], 
[Limit1].[Plant] AS [Plant], 
[Limit1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
[Limit1].[PostedToKeystone] AS [PostedToKeystone], 
[Limit1].[EmailSuccess] AS [EmailSuccess], 
[Limit1].[EmailRecipients] AS [EmailRecipients], 
[Limit1].[FormType] AS [FormType], 
[Limit1].[Usage] AS [Usage], 
[Limit1].[JobId] AS [JobId], 
[Limit1].[JobLot] AS [JobLot], 
[Limit1].[CustomerPo] AS [CustomerPo], 
[Limit1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
[Limit1].[PostedToKeystoneDate] AS [PostedToKeystoneDate], 
[Limit1].[Devices_DeviceId] AS [Devices_DeviceId]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[TicketTrackerId] AS [TicketTrackerId], 
    [Extent1].[BusinessId] AS [BusinessId], 
    [Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], 
    [Extent1].[ETicketStorageId] AS [ETicketStorageId], 
    [Extent1].[TicketJSON] AS [TicketJSON], 
    [Extent1].[DriverUpdateId] AS [DriverUpdateId], 
    [Extent1].[OrderNumber] AS [OrderNumber], 
    [Extent1].[OrderKey] AS [OrderKey], 
    [Extent1].[TicketNumber] AS [TicketNumber], 
    [Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
    [Extent1].[VehicleId] AS [VehicleId], 
    [Extent1].[Plant] AS [Plant], 
    [Extent1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
    [Extent1].[PostedToKeystone] AS [PostedToKeystone], 
    [Extent1].[EmailSuccess] AS [EmailSuccess], 
    [Extent1].[EmailRecipients] AS [EmailRecipients], 
    [Extent1].[FormType] AS [FormType], 
    [Extent1].[Usage] AS [Usage], 
    [Extent1].[JobId] AS [JobId], 
    [Extent1].[JobLot] AS [JobLot], 
    [Extent1].[CustomerPo] AS [CustomerPo], 
    [Extent1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
    [Extent1].[PostedToKeystoneDate] AS [PostedToKeystoneDate], 
    [Extent1].[Devices_DeviceId] AS [Devices_DeviceId]
    FROM [ETicket].[TicketTracker] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[TicketTrackerId] = @p0
)  AS [Limit1]
GO

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[TicketTrackerId] AS [TicketTrackerId], 
    [Extent1].[BusinessId] AS [BusinessId], 
    [Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], 
    [Extent1].[ETicketStorageId] AS [ETicketStorageId], 
    [Extent1].[TicketJSON] AS [TicketJSON], 
    [Extent1].[DriverUpdateId] AS [DriverUpdateId], 
    [Extent1].[OrderNumber] AS [OrderNumber], 
    [Extent1].[OrderKey] AS [OrderKey], 
    [Extent1].[TicketNumber] AS [TicketNumber], 
    [Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
    [Extent1].[VehicleId] AS [VehicleId], 
    [Extent1].[Plant] AS [Plant], 
    [Extent1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
    [Extent1].[PostedToKeystone] AS [PostedToKeystone], 
    [Extent1].[EmailSuccess] AS [EmailSuccess], 
    [Extent1].[EmailRecipients] AS [EmailRecipients], 
    [Extent1].[FormType] AS [FormType], 
    [Extent1].[Usage] AS [Usage], 
    [Extent1].[JobId] AS [JobId], 
    [Extent1].[JobLot] AS [JobLot], 
    [Extent1].[CustomerPo] AS [CustomerPo], 
    [Extent1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
    [Extent1].[PostedToKeystoneDate] AS [PostedToKeystoneDate], 
    [Extent1].[Devices_DeviceId] AS [Devices_DeviceId]
    FROM [ETicket].[TicketTracker] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 11277 = [Extent1].[TicketTrackerId]
```

I would love for Find to simply generate a select statement but before I start switching code, is there a reason EF adds this complex query with a simple method? I did read that Find uses internal caching and Where doesn't, but other than that what am I missing?

Comment: Why does it matter? What problems does it cause?

Comment: EF is very verbose. It writes its queries with a high amount of detail as to prevent any possible confusion with other objects in your database.

Comment: In Azure when looking at query performance, this query is always either taking up too many resources or is the slowest. I'm just trying to figure out why.

Comment: @GHDevOps This sounds like a potential indexing issue in your database.

Comment: TOP 2 is normally indicative of a Single[OrDefault] - is the code accurate?

Comment: @JeffB It was an indexing issue! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @GHDevOps Sure thing, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see random queries running slow for seemingly no reason, or resource consumption is really high this is often a sign of an indexing issue.

-- Putting this answer here as this was in fact the issue with the OPs query.

Answer (score 1):

Those queries are normal and shouldn't cause any performance problems.  For some  more complex queries you may find that it's worth writing a custom [Raw SQL Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql), but not in this case.

> this query is always either taking up too many resources or is the slowest.

Turn on the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) to find out what resources it's taking and why it's slow.